# Started this problem but can't finish it: Showing pointwise convergence for this summation

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convergence-divergence

I know how to start this problem but am having trouble finishing the end of it. Any help would be great! Thanks

We let $g_n: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions for $1 \leq n \leq N$ and we let $a_k^{(n)}$ be $N$ convergent sequences of numbers. Assume lim$_{k\rightarrow \infty}a_k^{(n)} = a_n$. Let $f = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n g_n$.

I want to show that:

$\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_k^{\{n\}} g_n$ converges point-wise to $f$.

My solution so far:

Pointwise convergence definition: A sequence of functions $g_n$ defined on a set M converges pointwise to a function g on M if lim $f_n(x)$ = $f(x)$ as n $\rightarrow$ ∞ holds for all $x$ in M.

I can fix $x$ in $E$ and then look at |$\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_k^{\{n\}}g_n(x)$ - $\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_ng_n(x)$|but from here I am do not know how to break this down to show pointwise convergence.

Comment: Did you try combining like terms in the difference?

Comment: I tried that, but I must have been doing something wrong because I did not get pointwise convergence. I must have been doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For all $1\leq n\leq N:\forall x \in E: a_k^{(n)}g_n(x)$ converges to $a^{(n)}g_n(x)$.

Therefore, their sum must also converge to the sum of the limits.

Comment: how did you arrive at that?

Comment: If you have two sequences $(u_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ and $(v_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$, which converge to $u$ and $v$ respectively. Then $(u_n+v_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ converges to $u+v$.  

I simply applied this $N-1$ times.

Comment: why did you do it N-1 times? I am still slightly confused

Comment: $a^1_kg_1(x)$ and $a^2_kg_2(x)$ converges to $a^1g_1(x)$ and $a^2g_2(x)$ respectively, so $a^1_kg_1(x)+a^2_kg_2(x)$ converges to $a^1g_1(x)+a^2g_2(x)$.  
$a^3_kg_3(x)$ converges to $a^3g_3(x)$, so $a^1_kg_1(x)+a^2_kg_2(x)+a^3_kg_3(x)$ converges to $a^1g_1(x)+a^2g_2(x)+a^3g_3(x)$. And so on  
at the last step, we have $a^1_kg_1(x)+\dots +a^N-1_kg_{N-1}(x)$ converges to $a^1g_1(x)+\dots +a^N-1g_{N-1}(x)$ and $a^N_kg_N(x)$ converges to $a^Ng_N(x)$ So $a^1_kg_1(x)+\dots+ a^N_kg_N(x)$  converges to $a^1g_1(x)+\dots +a^Ng_N(x)$

Comment: wow thanks for the detailed response! That makes complete sense. So with this approach I don't need to look at

|$\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_k^{\{n\}}g_n(x)$ - $\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_ng_n(x)$| right

Answer (score 0):

Hint: |$\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_k^{\{n\}}g_n(x)$ - $\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_ng_n(x)$| = $|\sum_{n=1}^N (a_k^{\{n\}} - a_n) g_n(x)|$.

Additionally, $|\sum_{n=0}^N x_n| \leq \sum_{n=0}^N |x_n|$ for any $x_n$ (this is the triangle inequality).

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Oh actually I had got to that part (I didn't think it was right at first since, I couldn't see how it was pointwise convergent after this stage)

Comment: I keep getting 0 not f for some reason

Comment: You should get zero. Well, not zero exactly, but arbitrarily close to zero

Comment: Do you know the definition of a limit? $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = x$ if the difference between $x_n$ and $x$ can be made arbitrarily small. The difference should go to zero, not to the limit.